# ¿return un mensaje si no se ejecuta correctamente la setencia preparada PHP?

Tags: php

Al intentar eliminar un registro que esta relacionado con otras tablas,
no entiendo porque en vez de retornarme el mensaje de "error", me retorna todo mensaje de error que arroja php:

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE cod_materia_prima_mp = :cod_materia_prima_mp");

      $stmt->bindParam(":cod_materia_prima_mp", $dato, PDO::PARAM_INT);

      if($stmt -> execute()){

         return "ok";

      }else{

         return "error";

      }

      $stmt -> close();

      $stmt = null;
```

pero si ese registro tiene relacion con otro me arroja es el sigueinte mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y para mi deberia retornar el mesensaje "error".

Comment: Por la integridad referencial, has un `show create table nombreTabla` de la tabla de dónde intentas eliminar y agrégalo a tu pregunta

Comment: necesito es mas bien como depurar si no se ejecuta la consulta, sin importar el error que arroje siempre retonar un mensaje de error en caso de que no se ejecute, el error es porque esta tabla esta relacionada con otras, y yo la tengo configurada para que no deje eliminar de esta tabla si estan relacionado con otras, por eso necisto arrojas un mensaje como "ERROR", o "oye esta dato esta relaconado con otra tabla, primero elimna los datos relacionado".

Comment: En pdo puedes obtener el mensaje de error real con el método errorInfo

Comment: si bro, realmente lo que necesito es que me retorne el mensaje de erro si no se jecuta la consulta, no lo que esta pasando que me retorna es todo mensaje fatal error.....

Comment: pero creo que ya lo solucione con un try catch PDOException, no se si es la mejor forma para lo que quiero.

Comment: Si la tabla tiene una restricción quizá sería mejor evitar que ese registro pueda ser elminado, así ahorrarías un largo proceso para nada en muchos casos. La política para manejarlo ya depende del contexto, pero me parece una mejor opción desde todos los puntos de vista. Si un registro no puede ser eliminado no debería aparecer en tu programa la posibilidad de eliminarlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano si me diste una buena idea, creo que podria hacer algo como si en otras tabla hay datos que me relacionan con este registro, entoces desabilitar el boton de eliminar, y algun mensaje al pasar el puntero por encima del boton, que diga este btn no puede ser habilitado, este registro esta relacionado con otros datos. igual por defecto en la bd tengo la restriccion para que no me deje eliminar esos registros, solo que buscaba eliminar ese error por ahora me funciona con un con un try catch PDOException.